# How can i get other contacts in android by using google people api

Tags: java, android, google-people-api

**I followed through the documention of people api** https://developers.google.com/people/v1/other-contacts.They already provided the function otherContacts() but it is not available in PeopleService class

```
ListOtherContactsResponse response = peopleService.otherContacts().list()
.setReadMask("metadata,names,emailAddresses")
.execute();

List<Person> otherContacts = response.getOtherContacts();
```

tried with this code but didn't find ListOtherContactsResponse class and otherContacts() in PeopleService. I am using these dependencies

```
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev277-1.23.0'
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! If you have any relevant code which might help others help you better, please include it in your question as well. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: Hi ! Are you getting any console error and if so, which error is it? **NOTE:** this is the [reference of otherContacts.list()](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/otherContacts/list) where you can also test request and see if it works with minimal effort. Try the API and let me know if that also fails. Thanks ! :D

Comment: @MateoRandwolf i am using android studio, android studio itself is saying that no function(otherContacts()) in PeopleService. Am i using the different old version of people service dependency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev20200720-1.30.10**
Finally this version solves my problem